# How to set multiple LDAP object classes with PHP?

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to receive user data from an Shibboleth/SAML IdP and pass it into an LDAP:

```
// Get data from IdP
$attributes = getUserFromIdP();

// Connect + bind (simplified)
$ldapconn = ldap_connect();
ldap_bind();

// Prepare data
$info['uid']                    = $attributes['uid'][0];
$info['givenName']              = $attributes['givenName'][0];
$info['sn']                     = $attributes['sn'][0];
$info['cn']                     = $attributes['cn'][0];
$info['mail']                   = $attributes['mail'][0];
$info['objectclass'][]          = 'inetOrgPerson';
$info['objectclass'][]          = 'eduPerson'; // problem here!

$dn = "cn=".$info['cn'].",dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=tld";
$r = ldap_add($ldapconn, $dn, $info);
```

It works fine if I only add `inetOrgPerson` as `objectclass`. But when I try to exclusively set `eduPerson` or both at the same time, I get an `Invalid syntax` error (error code 21).

It doesn't seem to be missing required attributes (that would throw a `Object class violation` error). So what is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: I need to import the `eduPerson` schema first. (A more specific error message would've helped...)